# sql procedure to print last day of month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write procedure to print day  month

There is no compilation error but its not printing anything.

Comment: `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before executing procedure

Comment: Its showing invalid after adding this line after begin

Comment: `sysdate` is of date format, and so is `to_d`. No need to use `to_date` here.

Comment: @constantlearner `set serveroutput on` is a SQL*PLUS command not a PL/SQL one.

Comment: Compiling a procedure doesn't run it. If you want to see the the output you have to run it.

Comment: Sysdate is already a date, so there is no need to convert it again using to_date().

Comment: want to add 12 months to this what shld i do I want last day to be next year aug 30 2014–

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P2 AS 
  to_d date;
BEGIN
  SELECT REP_DATE 
    INTO to_d 
    FROM cmpss_report_calender 
   WHERE REPID='F2';

  IF LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) =LAST_DAY(to_d) 
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('');
  ELSE 
    dbms_output.put_line(to_d);
  end if;

END P2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P2 AS 
  to_d date;
BEGIN
  SELECT REP_DATE 
    INTO to_d 
    FROM cmpss_report_calender 
   WHERE REPID='F2';

  IF LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) =LAST_DAY(to_d) 
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('');
  ELSE 
    dbms_output.put_line(to_d);
  end if;

END P2;
```

If you are using sql plus, do as

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

EXEC P2;
```

Comment: I want to print next year end date what can i change in this I want 30 8 2014  I tried add months

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving a blank line after the SET SERVEROUTPUT ON command. Also the SET SERVEROUTPUT ON is a SQL Plus command so make sure you are using the same.